# How concatenate 2 column that contains multiple rows of data

Tags: concatenation, row, talend

I work with Talend 6.3. I want to concatenate 2 columns in tmap. But in specifics rows, there are multiple data and i want match them the first with the first of the row in the other column.

Example :

- 2 columns  : Name and Surname
- In Name, I have : Kevin,Zoe,Alan
- In Surname, I have : Monta,Rey,Zom

I want an other row that concatenates Kevin with Monta, Zoe with Rey, Alan with Zom.

How do that with talend? Because in tmap if I concatenate classic, I will have only one success concatenation.

I don't know if I explained that correctly but tell me if someone need more information.

Thanks in advance

The job :

[image]

Add other data -> Login is the ID

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have a flow with an ID and 2 columns (Name and Surname), each contain *n* elements.
*n* can vary from row to row.

The goal is to have a final flow with the concatenation of all Name + Surname with the ID intact.

It's not a super Talend-y way, but you can use tFlowToIterate to access each row individually and do the pairing of Name + Surname.

After, we access the resulting list and use tNormalize to split it :

[image: screenshot job]

Code for the tJava component :

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(((String)globalMap.get("row5.Name")).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
List<String> surnameList = Arrays.asList(((String)globalMap.get("row5.Surname")).split("\\s*,\\s*"));

for (int index = 0; index < nameList.size(); index++) {
    ((ArrayList<String>) context.concat).add(((Integer)globalMap.get("row5.id")) + ";" + nameList.get(index) + ";" + surnameList.get(index));
}
```

Code for the tFixedFlowInput "Use context (list)" :

```
StringHandling.EREPLACE(StringHandling.EREPLACE(context.concat.toString(),"\\[",""),"\\]","")
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209574/discussion-on-answer-by-carassus-how-concatenate-2-column-that-contains-multiple).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry like that : 
[image]

The concatenation work when i have only one data in the column. Only Kevin and only Monta in cels.
Maybe it's cause of my tDernormalize in the schema.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That the code to set the global var with the list

[image]

That the code to get my list

[image]

And i have this result (the first have organisation empty, the first and the second have to have santeffi, don't look the first column, the second is the good one)
[image]

that data before javaRow (code and libelle are in different column)
[image]